# Extract the middle part of a column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, extract, server-side

All of my part numbers are formated as "00-00000-00" in column "part_no"

I need to create a new column that extracts only the middle part, the five characters between "00" and "-00" of the part number.

Is it possible to create this result when a record is created via php?

Thanks

Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to create the column to hold that data, then you have to do this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET newColumnName = SUBSTR(part_number,4,5);
```

Comment: Thank you.  To achieve this on the client side when I create a new record, could ad a line to this:  $order = "INSERT INTO cartons_added (add_time, type, part_no, add_type, add_qty, add_ref, add_by, add_notes)
   VALUES
('$date',
 '$_POST[type]', 
 '$_POST[part_no]', 
 '$_POST[add_type]', 
 '$_POST[add_qty]', 
 '$_POST[add_ref]', 
 '$_POST[add_by]', 
 '$_POST[add_notes]')";

Comment: there's no client side with PHP, remember that everything in php is executed on the server side. And if you want to generate this value when you insert a record you can do it directly with PHP or pass part of the logic to the RDBMS using triggers

Answer (score 3):

```
select substring(part_no, 4, 5) as middle_part
from your_table
```

Comment: Is it possible to create this result when a record is created via php?

Comment: You mean in a insert statement? try `insert into your_table (part_no) values (substring('00-00000-00', 4, 5))`

Comment: This works great, but I need to make it permanent for all existing records:What would I change?  select substring(part_no, 5, 5) as core
from cartons_cuurrent

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = mb_substr($old, 3, -3);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Answer (score -1):

```
    $result = "00-00000-00";
    $answer = substr($result, 3, 5);
```